# Compute weight of a point on a 3D triangle

Tags: geometry, 3d

Let's say I have a 3D triangle $ABC$ with $x$, a random point on it, I know the coordinates of each one of the points.
Each of $A$, $B$ and $C$ have a "weight" which is a decimal value between 0 and 1 (actually the color value of the point on a black and white gradient). What I want to do is to find the precise weight of $x$, knowing that the weight interpolation between the points is linear.

What formula should I use?

[image: ABC triangle with x point on it]

Comment: According to your image, it seems as if the decimal values indicate a black-white color gradient, but we do not know anything about how the gradient is determined. Is it pure white in the top right corner, and pure black in the bottom left? Does it change linearly between the two extremes, or is there some other description of the colors in between?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697521/interpolation-of-a-triangle.) could be a good starting point for you.

Comment: @shardulc The weights can be 0 if they're pure black, and 1 if they are pure white, the map is painted by the user so the weight of each point can vary between those values, and the interpolation is linear.

Comment: The link given by @AugSB points to [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/383804/calculate-uv-coordinates-of-3d-point-on-plane-of-m.html). Quoting from the page (emphasis mine): "Once you have the barycentric coordinates (or *interpolation factors*), any values associated to the vertices can be interpolated exactly the same way: *colors*, normals, depth, custom values, whatever." The techniques used on that page are quite straightforward and can be 'degeneralized' to two dimensions without trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look but I'm a bit lost, especially with that UV thing...

Comment: From B run a line through x that intersect AC - point D. Calculate the weight of D based on A and C. Calculate x based on D and B.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on my comment: [This webpage](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/383804/calculate-uv-coordinates-of-3d-point-on-plane-of-m.html) describes a good method to interpolate and find the *barycentric* coordinates of a point inside a triangle, which can easily be used to calculate the 'weight' or color of the point as asked by the OP. The method involves first representing the triangle as a triplet of vectors $(\mathbf{a} = (a_x, a_y), \mathbf{b} = (b_x, b_y), \mathbf{c} = (c_x, c_y))$ and the point as another vector $\mathbf{p} = (p_x, p_y)$. (The linked webpage uses 3-dimensional vectors but the method is generalizable.)

Once the vectors are obtained, we can calculate the areas of the triangles formed by joining the vertices of the triangle to the point inside it. The area of the whole triangle is
$$\Delta = \frac{1}{2} \cdot ||\mathbf{a} - \mathbf{b}|| \cdot ||\mathbf{a} - \mathbf{c}||$$
(which is half the magnitude of the cross product of the two vectors). The areas of the triangles opposite vertices $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{c}$, respectively, are
$$
\Delta_a = \frac{1}{2} \cdot ||\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{b}|| \cdot ||\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{c}|| \\
\Delta_b = \frac{1}{2} \cdot ||\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{a}|| \cdot ||\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{c}|| \\
\Delta_c = \frac{1}{2} \cdot ||\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{a}|| \cdot ||\mathbf{p} - \mathbf{b}||
$$

Now, we calculate the 'interpolation factors' of the point $\mathbf{p}$ as $k_a = \frac{\Delta_a}{\Delta}$, $k_b = \frac{\Delta_b}{\Delta}$, and $k_c = \frac{\Delta_c}{\Delta}$. The barycentric coordinates of $\mathbf{p}$ are finally given by
$$\mathbf{p} = \mathbf{a}k_a + \mathbf{b}k_b + \mathbf{c}k_c$$
(In the linked page, they use 'UV' coordinates, but since we are using 2 dimensions throughout, our 'UV' coordiantes are the same as our 'XY[Z]' coordinates.)

If $w_a$, $w_b$, $w_c$ denote the weights of, or colors of, or amount of cheese contained in, the points $\mathbf{a}$, $\mathbf{b}$, and $\mathbf{c}$, respectively, then $w_p = w_ak_a + w_bk_b + w_ck_c$ is the corresponding quantity for $\mathbf{p}$, assuming the 'linear' interpolation.

*Extra:* It would be interesting if this technique could be generalized to any polygon, using the areas opposite the vertices or something similar. I don't know much about this, but perhaps someone more knowledgeable can comment.

*Edit:* The answer to the above is very simple, just use a triangle within the polygon that contains the point. I overlooked that :)